# test isp for bandwidth throttling

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, bandwidth, throttling

As of late youtube has been slow to load like 30-45 seconds in it will pause and buffer for 2-3 min. this happens on my wifes mac , my desktop and my work laptop so im pretty sure its not a hardware issue. (as a test my work laptop youtubes just fine at work)

other "various" videos load with out a hickup at full 1080 res and even netflix has been pretty snappy.

Is this bandwidth throttling and is there a good way to test on my end.
I'm also suspicious of the crapy combo router/modem they supplied but this problem seems like its only a few weeks old and we've had the same router for about 3.5 years

suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a couple of problems. I doubt you are being throttled unless you are consuming large amounts of data. If so going over the fair usage agreement limits will get you sin-binned.

To start off you ought to reboot the router.  Switch it off and wait 30 seconds to clear the cache.

Check youtube to see if you have an improvement. Are you behind a proxy? If you are it might be an idea to disable the setting to the proxy server.

If not improved change the DNS settings on your router. It is recommended that you stick to those of your ISP but sometimes changing can improve your speed. Pick one that is local to you ie the same country.

If that does not fix the problem get a new router. Do not bother with low end routers. They tend to overheat and need frequent rebooting. Building your own router is possible but is more expensive in running cost (although a Raspberry Pi would use the same or less power than a standard router).